# file and number of lines matching

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to count lines in the files which matches to the given pattern. now the problem is it gives me only the number of lines. How can i get the file location or name along with number of matched lines?

command i am using now is

```
for i in $(find . -name 'foo.txt' | sed 's/\.\///g');
do
    grep -l && -c '^>' $i;
done
```

so output i am expecting is like "file location/name number of lines matching"

Comment: Welcome to [so]! `grep -l && -c '^>' $i` doesn't look like a valid command. Mind to provide some sample input and desired output?

Comment: [Don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You capture the number of lines matching in a variable and test it:

```
n=$(grep -c '^>' "$i")
(( n > 0 )) && echo "$i:$n"
```

Actually, you don't even need the test: grep exits unsuccessfully if no matches found, so

```
n=$(grep -c '^>' "$i") && echo "$i:$n"
```

---

Actually, that's too much work. With GNU grep at least, use the `-H` option. A demo with a file I have lying around:

```
$ grep -c zero note.xml
16
$ grep -Hc zero note.xml
note.xml:16
```

Comment: Thanks a lot glenn jackman.. it works for me with small modifications.. :)

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can show you the file name if you specify it as a command-line argument. You can use `xargs` to invoke grep for each batch of filenames. It'll read the names from standard input and use them as command line arguments for grep.

```
find . | xargs grep -cH '^>'
```

Using your `find` command:

```
find . -name 'foo.txt' | sed 's/\.\///g' | xargs grep -cH '^>'
```

Comment: Add the `-H` grep option (in case xargs is left with only one file), and this is the best answer

Comment: Or equivalently supply `/dev/null` as a file name argument, so that there is always more than one file; but explicitly specifying `-H` is certainly more elegant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Rob Davis